# Python import Dynamic or Static License restriction

Tags: python, licensing, python-import

I have Python application which needs to be released commercially ( Closed Source), We are using some modules which are licensed GPL.

If I understood correctly then GPL put restrictions that I can not link GPL code statically if I want to release it under closed source.

Some other questions for dynamic import suggest using `__import__` but I think that will work the same way, atleast when we will generate the binaries.

Comment: I believe (but I'm not a lawyer), that it's illegal either way. If you link with GPL'd components, your binary is GPL'd.

Comment: I am not a lawyer either, but from what I understand, only LGPL lets you do the dynamic import loophole. GPL turns everything it touches into GPL as well since it is viewed as an expansion to the code. In a few cases, you can find LGPL libraries that have API's very similar to their GLP brothers (Like PyQt(GPL) vs PySide(LGPL)) Good luck.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to speak to a lawyer (or several), but larsmans is essentially correct; if your code incorporates GPL code then you must release the source code in accordance with the terms of the GPL.  If that's not an option, for whatever reason, then you need to find replacements for the GPL code.  Even if you're only importing modules licensed under the GPL then you still need to release that much of it.